# what is the alternative for network info in android since its depriciated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
    class ConnectionManager
{
    fun checkConnectivity(context: Context):Boolean
    {
        val connectivityManager=context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo?=connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        if(activeNetwork?.isConnected!=null)
        {
            return activeNetwork.isConnected

        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**I have used the above code in android kotlin to check network connectivity the issue is activenetworkinfo ,isconnected,networkinfo are deprecated in java what alternative can I use**

Answer (score 0):

This is the extension I use

```
/**
 * Returns if a network connection is available or not.
 */
@SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
fun Context.isOnline(): Boolean {
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val n = cm.activeNetwork
        if (n != null) {
            val nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n)
            //It will check for both wifi and cellular network
            return nc!!.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        }
        return false
    } else {
        val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }
}
```

Comment: but u are  using active network info,isConnectedOrConnecting which is depreciated

Comment: and this also doesn't include Ethernet transport.